# Ref & out overloaded methods

Tags: c#

How the below methods are not considered as overloaded

```
public void SampleMethod(out int i) { }
public void SampleMethod(ref int i) { }
```

How the below methods are considered as overloaded. Can you please explain ?

```
public void SampleMethod(int i) { }
public void SampleMethod(ref int i) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

At the IL level, `ref` and `out` have the same signature; `out` is a lie - it only exists as a compiler hint that lets you get away with certain liberties : it is really `ref` in a mask. In fact, you can implement an `out` method in IL that reads the incoming value (which may not have been assigned a definite value - it'll be whatever it happens to be, usually zero due to `.locals init`).

By contrast, `int i` and `ref int i` have different signatures; `int i` takes an `int` value on the stack; `ref int i` takes a *managed pointer to an `int`* on the stack. So at the IL level, these are as different as `int i` vs `bool b` : they are different types / signatures.